# 90's (or earlier) book about a super-human who was the oldest rookie in the NFL

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m looking for this science-fiction book (in English) that I read in the early 90’s.  It started out with a 40+ year old man who became the oldest rookie in American football (NFL.)

It was a super-human story, ending with the man becoming god-like with creation powers.  He eventually got bored because he could experience anything he wanted such as being loved by a woman whom he used to love.

I am pretty sure he gained his powers late in life - the “oldest rookie in NFL” thing happened right at the start of the book to showcase his newfound powers. I really don’t remember how he got them, but his powers increased exponentially from there, for example it was just being stronger and faster in the beginning but later he could reshape reality.

I think it had “Flying Dutchman” or something similar in the title but I’m fuzzy about this.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Do you remember perhaps how he gained these super-powers? Through some comic trope of being bitten by something, radiation, a wish? Or did he have the powers from birth?

Comment: I am pretty sure he gained his powers late in life - the “oldest rookie in NFL” thing happened right at the start of the book to showcase his newfound powers.  Really don’t remember how he got them but his powers increased exponentially from there(ie it was just being stronger faster in the beginning but later he could reshape reality etc)